# Delete object in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

My problem here is that when I have 2 objects in array it loop 2x then asks for another "Are you sure you want to delete it?". Can't figure out my loop. Here is the code:

```
for (Iterator<Student> it = student.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

    Student stud = it.next();
    do {
        System.out.print("Are you sure you want to delete it?");
        String confirmDelete = scan.next();

        ynOnly = false;

        if (confirmDelete.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
                && stud.getStudNum().equals(enterStudNum2)) {
            it.remove();
            System.out.print("Delete Successful");
            ynOnly = false;
        } else if (confirmDelete.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.print("Deletion did not proceed");
            ynOnly = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nY or N only\n");
            ynOnly = true;
        }
    } while (ynOnly == true);

}
```

Comment: you should understand the difference between a `do/while` loop and a `while` loop :)

Comment: @Trafalgar law: For two objects in your list, you should see "Are you sure...?" twice and "Delete Successful" twice, assuming you're pressing 'y'/'Y' for each iteration of the loop and `stud.getStudNum().equals(enterStudNum2)` is `true`. What's your output?

Comment: @Voicu The output is like this .. 

Delete successful 
Are you sure you want to delete it?

it asking for another confirmation
instead of just one confirmation

Comment: @Trafalgarlaw: That should be because there is another object in the list to be deleted. Make sure you output the size of the list to know how many times you will be prompted for deletion. Step by step debugging won't hurt either.

Comment: @Voicu tnx ill try it

Answer (score 0):

Its because of two loops going on there. Your inner loops terminate after the value of `ynOnly` becomes false but outer loop still continues. You might want something like that--

```
for (Iterator<Student> it = student.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

Student stud = it.next();
if(!stud.getStudNum().equals(enterStudNum2))
            continue;                            //you want only that student to be deleted which has enterStudNum2 so let other record skip
do {
    System.out.print("Are you sure you want to delete it?");
    String confirmDelete = scan.next();

    ynOnly = false;

    if (confirmDelete.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
            && stud.getStudNum().equals(enterStudNum2)) {
        it.remove();
        System.out.print("Delete Successful");
        ynOnly = false;
    } else if (confirmDelete.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        System.out.print("Deletion did not proceed");
        ynOnly = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nY or N only\n");
        ynOnly = true;
    }
} while (ynOnly == true);
```

}